# ASN1 Structure Procuration Syntax

Tags: certificate, openssl, x509

I want to add the Procuration Extension to my Certificate. Therefor i use the Tool XCA, which uses OpenSSL conf to create the certificates.

This is the ASN1 structure:

```
ProcurationSyntax ::= SEQUENCE
{
    country [1] EXPLICIT PrintableString OPTIONAL
    typeOfSubstitution[2] EXPLICIT DirectoryString OPTIONAL
    signingFor [3] EXPLICIT SigningFor
}

SigningFor ::= CHOICE
{
    thirdPerson GeneralName
    certRef IssuerSerial
}

IssuerSerial ::= SEQUENCE
{
    issuer GeneralNames
    serial CertificateSerialNumber
    issuerUID UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL
}
```

Now i want to add this Extension as arbitrary Extension via openssl conf (https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/x509v3_config.html#ARBITRARY-EXTENSIONS)

My code looks this, but i stuck at the rest - thirdPerson stuff:

```
1.3.36.8.3.2=ASN1:SEQUENCE:proc_sect

[proc_sect]
country=EXPLICIT:1,IA5STRING:EN
typeOfSubtitution=EXPLICIT:2,IA5STRING:My Type of Substitution
thirdPerson OR certRef=EXPLICIT:3,TODO
```

So it would be very helpful if someone could provide working example code of the missing rest, that is thirdPerson and certRef.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Minimal example of the whole thing

```
1.3.36.8.3.2 = ASN1:SEQUENCE:procuration

[procuration]
country            = EXP:1, PRINTABLE:EN
typeOfSubstitution = EXP:2, UTF8:My Type of Substitution
thirdPerson        = EXP:3, EXP:0, EXP:1, IA5:fred@example.com
```

To obtain a test case, I compiled the following ASN.1 value notation using [asn1-playground](http://asn1-playground.oss.com/):

```
procuration ProcurationSyntax ::= {
  country "EN",
  typeOfSubstitution utf8String : "My Type of Substitution",
  signingFor thirdPerson rfc822Name : "fred@example.com"
}
```

I used this schema:

```
-- RFC 5280 Appendix A.1
PKIX1Explicit88 DEFINITIONS EXPLICIT TAGS ::=
BEGIN
    Name ::= CHOICE { -- only one possibility for now --
          rdnSequence  RDNSequence }

    RDNSequence ::= SEQUENCE OF RelativeDistinguishedName

    DistinguishedName ::= RDNSequence

    RelativeDistinguishedName ::= SET SIZE (1..MAX) OF AttributeTypeAndValue

    AttributeTypeAndValue ::= SEQUENCE {
            type    AttributeType,
            value   AttributeValue }

    AttributeType ::= OBJECT IDENTIFIER

    AttributeValue ::= ANY -- DEFINED BY AttributeType

    DirectoryString ::= CHOICE {
          teletexString       TeletexString   (SIZE (1..MAX)),
          printableString     PrintableString (SIZE (1..MAX)),
          universalString     UniversalString (SIZE (1..MAX)),
          utf8String          UTF8String      (SIZE (1..MAX)),
          bmpString           BMPString       (SIZE (1..MAX)) }

    CertificateSerialNumber  ::=  INTEGER

    UniqueIdentifier  ::=  BIT STRING
END

-- RFC 5280 Appendix A.2
PKIX1Implicit88 DEFINITIONS IMPLICIT TAGS ::=
BEGIN
    IMPORTS
        DirectoryString,
        Name
        FROM PKIX1Explicit88;

    GeneralNames ::= SEQUENCE SIZE (1..MAX) OF GeneralName

    GeneralName ::= CHOICE {
         otherName                 [0]  AnotherName,
         rfc822Name                [1]  IA5String,
         dNSName                   [2]  IA5String,
         --x400Address               [3]  ORAddress,
         directoryName             [4]  Name,
         --ediPartyName              [5]  EDIPartyName,
         uniformResourceIdentifier [6]  IA5String,
         iPAddress                 [7]  OCTET STRING,
         registeredID              [8]  OBJECT IDENTIFIER }

    AnotherName ::= SEQUENCE {
         type-id    OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
         value      [0] EXPLICIT ANY DEFINED BY type-id }
END

-- Foo
Procuration-Schema DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::=
BEGIN
    IMPORTS
        CertificateSerialNumber, DirectoryString, UniqueIdentifier FROM PKIX1Explicit88
        GeneralName, GeneralNames FROM PKIX1Implicit88;

    ProcurationSyntax ::= SEQUENCE
    {
        country [1] EXPLICIT PrintableString OPTIONAL,
        typeOfSubstitution[2] EXPLICIT DirectoryString OPTIONAL,
        signingFor [3] EXPLICIT SigningFor
    }

    SigningFor ::= CHOICE
    {
        thirdPerson GeneralName,
        certRef IssuerSerial
    }

    IssuerSerial ::= SEQUENCE
    {
        issuer GeneralNames,
        serial CertificateSerialNumber,
        issuerUID UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL
    }
END
```

This OpenSSL.cfg may also work:

```
[v3]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
1.3.36.8.3.2 = ASN1:SEQUENCE:procuration

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = ldap.example.com
DNS.2 = ldap1.example.com

[procuration]
country = EXPLICIT:1, PRINTABLE:EN
typeOfSubstitution = EXPLICIT:2, UTF8:My Type of Substitution
thirdPerson = EXPLICIT:3, EXPLICIT:0, IMP:1, IA5:fred@example.com
#certRef = EXPLICIT:3, IMP:1, SEQUENCE:cert_ref

#[cert_ref]
#issuer = IMP:0, SEQUENCE:proc_certref_issuer
#serial = IMP:1, INTEGER:12345

#[proc_certref_issuer]
#1 = IMP:1, IA5:bar
#2 = EXP:4, IMP:1, IMP:16U, FORMAT:HEX, #OCTETSTRING:3035310b30090603550406130245553110300e060355040a0c074578616d706c653114301206035504030c0b4672656420466f6f626172
```

#### [proc]

Pay attention to the various distinct string types.

**`country`** is defined as PrintableString (which is only a *subset* of IA5String):

```
country = EXPLICIT:1, PRINTABLE:EN
```

**`typeOfSubstitution`** is defined as [DirectoryString](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#page-116), which is a CHOICE between TeletexString, PrintableString, UniversalString, UTF8String, or BMPString – some of which are subsets of IA5String, others are supersets, but the *actual* IA5String is not actually permitted. So let's go with UTF-8 Unicode:

```
;                            ┌── tag for ProcurationSyntax sequence
;                            ¦
typeOfSubstitution = EXPLICIT:2, UTF8:My Type of Substitution
```

*(The online asn1step says there's no separate tag for DirectoryString choice; I guess that's because all the possible choices have unique 'universal' tags already.)*

Because **`signingFor`** is a CHOICE between `thirdPerson` vs `certRef`, you can include one *or* the other, and **it's up to you to select the apropriate type.**

**`thirdPerson`** is defined as [0] [GeneralName](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#page-38), which is a CHOICE between various further types – exactly the same selection as in the subjectAltName extension. For example, you may include an email address (in the form of rfc822Name [1] IA5String):

```
;                ┌── tag for ProcurationSyntax sequence
;                │      ┌── tag for SigningFor choice
;                │      │      ┌── tag for GeneralName choice
;                ¦      ¦      ¦
thirdPerson = EXP:3, EXP:0, EXP:1, IA5:fred@example.com
```

Or a dNSName (defined as [2] IA5String):

```
thirdPerson = EXP:3, EXP:0, EXP:2, IA5:example.com
```

(Or an otherName containing a MPEG video of a kitten.)

If, instead, you want to choose a **`certRef`**, that's a whole nested SEQUENCE.

```
;            ┌── tag for ProcurationSyntax sequence
;            │      ┌── tag for SigningFor choice
;            ¦      ¦
certRef = EXP:3, IMP:1, SEQUENCE:proc_certref
```

#### [proc_certref]

Inside the `[proc_certref]` section, you have to define at least `issuer` and `serial`.

**`issuer`** is [GeneralNames](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#page-38), which is a sequence of GeneralName values.

```
issuer = IMP:0, SEQUENCE:proc_certref_issuer
;           └── tag for IssuerSerial sequence
```

**`serial`** is [CertificateSerialNumber](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#page-17) is simply an integer.

```
serial = IMP:1, INTEGER:0x123456
```

**Note:** I'm very much unsure about whether these should have implicit tags or not.

#### [proc_certref_issuer]

Great. Another section, and a *GeneralNames* at that. Fortunately, there's only one of it. Unfortunately, there's more than zero of it.

The simplest valid value would be a single GeneralName which is just a rfc822Name or a dNSName (both IA5String):

```
issuer.0 = IMP:1, IA5:fred@example.com
;             └── tag for GeneralName choice
```

…actually, [we already did a directoryName once, didn't we?](https://superuser.com/a/939900) Because this `issuer.0` is a GeneralName, it uses the exact same format as `admissionAuthority` in your *previous* extension (with same tagging and everything) – so I won't be trying to implement it here again.

Comment: thanks a lot for this very detailed explanation which helps me a lot and clarifies some points. I will take a deeper look on in the next days.

Comment: i took a look into it. Is the second EXPLICIT not too much? `thirdPerson = EXP:3, EXP:0, EXP:1, IA5:fred@example.com`?

Comment: Yes, the tags _might_ actually be wrong. I think it depends on what default tagging mode was used for the whole schema (your post doesn't include the `DEFINITIONS [<...> TAGS] ::=` header line so it's slightly ambiguous).

Comment: thanks for the hint. I will look for this `DEFINITIONS`and report.

Comment: thanks for the hint. I looked into the CommonPKI-Specification and found this information: CHOICE objects are always EXPLICITly tagged, independent of the default tagging modus. So your second `EXPLICIT? is correct or? But it does not contain information if the tags are 0 and 1 or 1 and 2.

Comment: I believe tags always start from 0 if not specified otherwise.

Comment: and what about the `CHOICE`Type. If there is no tag specified, then default tagging mode is `EXPLICIT`? But there has to be a tag, otherwise I can't identify what choice it is, can i?

Comment: I'm not sure. I would say SigningFor is on the verge of being ambiguous, so if I were designing the schema, I'd always add the explicit tags... (On the other hand, in DirectoryString all possible choices already have distinct UNIVERSAL tags, so additional tagging is _apparently_ not needed.) This is beyond my ASN.1 knowledge.

Comment: As i see it there default mode is Explicit. But the `IMPLICIT` tags on serial, issuer and issuerUID are not right, because no tags are given in the basestructure definition, so it will be `EXPLICIT` by default or i'm wrong?